# MongoDB is not scaling

Tags: mongodb, performance, redis, latency

I am building out some tools that require <1s response times and using Mongo (or SQL for that matter) will resolve that. I am pretty sure that I'll need to either use Redis or some in-memory data structure. Right now my Mongo aggregate takes almost 5 seconds to load 30 rows. All the collections are indexed but there are lookups within lookups which I think is where the issue lies (i.e. having a reference to the user and having multiple users, need to get their personal info). I also have pagination enabled and on Mongo 5.0 (which uses indexes for sub lookups) Few questions:

1. Should I just switch to a SQL database?
2. Should I add change streams to the collection I need to query and update a redis instance and read from there?
3. Should I just embed the information I'm extracting from the lookups into the parent document
4. Do 2 and 3?

Comment: NoSQL databases like MongoDB are not optimized for joins, some NoSQL database do not even support joins at all. Typically the number of collections in a NoSQL database is much less than the number of tables in according application at a SQL RDBMS. You should design your data model according to the used database (i.e. "yes" for item 3). However, 30 records is nothing, no matter if SQL or NoSQL. There must be a different issue in your application, it is just ridicules to mention term "scaling" for 30 records.

Comment: Figured it is better to use SQL. And by 30 records, I am talking about setting the limit of results to 30 at a time off of a data set with millions of rows